# Generic type for object type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm writing a class and in the constructor i can pass a parameter which is an array of object:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(p: Array<CustomObject>) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Now, the class doesn't really matters, what does instead is the `CustomType` typescript type. I would like to create a type that can be "dynamic" (or better, have dynamic properties) based on a single property value.

I know in typescript we can use generics for functions like this:

```
function foo<T extends 'bar' | 'baz'>(x: T) {
    // TODO
}
```

And this way we don't have to define the generic each time we use that function, we just call it passing the `x` parameter and typescript will infer the type, but with object?

I need something like:

```
type CustomObject<T extends 1 | 2> = {
    x: T    // Here i need typescript to infer the type
}
```

In order to use it like so:

```
const obj: CustomObject = {
    x: 1    // Now typescript knows the type without explicitly setting it as a generic
}
```

Up to now i tried the example above (of course failed) and obviously the class approach:

```
class CustomObject<T extends 1 | 2> {
    constructor(init: { x: T }) {
        // TODO
    }
}

const obj = new CustomObject({ x: 1 }) // This way typescript knows the type and i don't have to pass a generic
```

I just wanted to know if there is a way to define a dynamic object type without using classes. Any answer is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a dynamic object. Would you like typescript to infer your object's values without having to explicitly pass a generic argument?

Comment: @see `satisfies` keyword, TS 4.9

Comment: @OGreeni I need to declare object's properties types based on a single (main) prop type so that if the main prop type is for example string then another prop would be number and if the main prop is a number the other prop would be string

Comment: @Dimava no, the "satisfies" keyword it's not what i need here, but thanks for your time

Comment: @Nick in this case, just use a union of the prop combinations. For instance, `class CustomObject<T extends {x: number, y: string} | {x: string, y: number}> { ... }`

Comment: There is currently no way to ask the compiler to infer a type argument; maybe if [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) is ever implemented it will be. For now the workaround is to introduce a generic helper function to take advantage of type argument inference.  So instead of `const x: Gen = ...` you'd write `const x = get(...)`.  For your example it looks like [this (web IDE link)](https://tsplay.dev/w2p2jm). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to ping me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz You're right, that was what i was thinking about, i can't use functions due to the purpose of this script but i really thank you for your explanation with examples and references. If you post an answer i'll mark it as correct for future cases

Comment: @OGreeni I know i can do it with classes, my question was about achieving the same with object literal type and generics, but thank you for your comment

Comment: "I can't use functions due to the purpose of this script" <-- what does this mean, exactly?  Can you demonstrate the use case that causes that not to work?  (I see that you got an answer already about using a function, so I probably won't write my own)

Comment: @jcalz This is a npm package and i would like to have object declared in this way so if a user wants to have a "CustomObject" object without using a function can declare a const with that type. I just don't want to change the way a user can declare const on his own just for a single type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the same way, but with function instead of class

```
function CustomObject<T extends 1 | 2>(init: { x: T }) {
  return init;
}

const obj = CustomObject({ x: 1 })
```